# I want to use tensorflow's metric(pearson correlation) in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use tensorflow's metrics(streaming pearson correlation) in keras.
I search and write this code.
But this score which my code calculate doesn't match the score which numpy(corrcoef) calculated.

```
def correlation_coefficient(y_true, y_pred):


    pearson_r, update_op = tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation(y_pred, y_true)
    # find all variables created for this metric
    metric_vars = [i for i in tf.local_variables() if 'correlation_coefficient' in i.name.split('/')[1]]

    # Add metric variables to GLOBAL_VARIABLES collection.
    # They will be initialized for new session.
    for v in metric_vars:
        tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, v)

    # force to update metric values
    with tf.control_dependencies([update_op]):
        pearson_r = tf.identity(pearson_r)
        return pearson_r
```

Comment: Can you add an example of inputs, outputs and difference between the two methods?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to do it like this:

```
from keras import backend as K

def tf_pearson(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.contrib.metrics.streaming_pearson_correlation(y_pred, y_true)[1]

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy', tf_pearson])

# tensorflow variables need to be initialized before calling model.fit()
# there is also a tf.global_variables_initializer(); that one doesn't seem to do the trick
# You will still get a FailedPreconditionError
K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())

model.fit()
```

Basically, it's 2 things -- you need to initialize variables (using the `local` function, not `global`) after you compile the model (and the TF functions/variables have been used in your code), then you need to get the second part of the tuple back from the metric (which is the op_update, but seems to store the value).

Comment: from TF2 it doesn't work, do you have other solution?